# Delete Multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to delete multiple sheets. This code takes forever to delete the sheets, not sure how can I speed up the process. If someone can help me out, would be great.

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

Dim h As Long, RESA1() As Variant

RESA1 = Array("Upload EC", "V-UploadEC", "EC Proj Data", "Orion SA Proj Data", _
    "Orion SA Data Table", "Proj Data", "Tables our", "Qty", "Multi Sites", "Data table" _
    , "Tbls", "Match", "Cov", "Quote", "Agg Quote", "RFQ", "Contractor", "HEER", "HEER_L", _
    "Site Decl", "Post Decl", "$", "$Enl", "ESInfo", "NBB Training", "T&C", "Work Order", "Installer Contract", "Recycle", "Rent", "PM", _
    "Xero", "Xero prep", "T&C Quote", "T&C VIC", "T&C noCert", "N-Nom", "CB PM Ledger", _
    "N-A9s", "N-A10s", "V-A-Lamp-Ballast", "VEET LCP", "VEU_LCP_35", "V-B-Space", _
    "V18 tbls", "V-C-BCA", "V-Compliance", "V-other", "ESS Other", "VIC pcode")

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For h = LBound(RESA1) To UBound(RESA1)
    Worksheets(RESA1(h)).Delete
Next h



Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: how many sheets are left? you could just save those to a new file instead...

Comment: Sometimes I need to leave 1 sheet left or 3 left. I can't as there is a lot of linked formulas.

Comment: well do the normal thing then and disable screen updating and calculations... i'm sure you know how to do that already

Comment: yes, still pretty slow. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yeah, that's excel for ya

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely 100% sure that all the listed sheets are going to be in the workbook then you don't need to loop through sheets when deleting, but if not, then, as BraX mentioned in the comments, your best bet is to turn off screen updating etc.

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Upload EC", "V-UploadEC", "EC Proj Data", "Orion SA Proj Data", _
    "Orion SA Data Table", "Proj Data", "Tables our", "Qty", "Multi Sites", "Data table" _
    , "Tbls", "Match", "Cov", "Quote", "Agg Quote", "RFQ", "Contractor", "HEER", "HEER_L", _
    "Site Decl", "Post Decl", "$", "$Enl", "ESInfo", "NBB Training", "T&C", "Work Order", "Installer Contract", "Recycle", "Rent", "PM", _
    "Xero", "Xero prep", "T&C Quote", "T&C VIC", "T&C noCert", "N-Nom", "CB PM Ledger", _
    "N-A9s", "N-A10s", "V-A-Lamp-Ballast", "VEET LCP", "VEU_LCP_35", "V-B-Space", _
    "V18 tbls", "V-C-BCA", "V-Compliance", "V-other", "ESS Other", "VIC pcode")) _
    .Delete    'directly deleting the sheets without looping

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```